# player.mute() not working in YouTube API with playlist

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, youtube-api

I want to mute a video after it plays for 9 seconds. I tested various things including `cuePlaylist` and other stuff.

Following is the code -

```
<div id="topplayer" align="center"></div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    var done = false;

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
});

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    topplayer = new YT.Player('topplayer', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      events: {
        'onReady': onTopPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onTopPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}

function onTopPlayerReady(event) {

    event.target.loadPlaylist({
        listType:'playlist',
        list: 'PL55713C70BA91BD6E',
        index: 0,
     });

    event.target.playVideo();
}

function onTopPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        setTimeout(muteVideo, 9000);
        done = true;
    }
}

function muteVideo() {
    topplayer.mute();
}
</script>
```

Now, with this code Video Playlist loads and autoruns (which I want) but it never mutes.

PS. I tried default example provided in official developers.google.com for YouTube API and changed `player.stopVideo()` to `player.mute()` and it works. So, I believe the problem is somewhere coming when am trying to load a playlist instead of a single video. The following code works well (it autoruns and mutes the video too) -

```
<div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.mute();
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your javascript; you define the `done` variable as local inside jQuery's `ready` method, and hence that variable is not available to any of the other methods (you can verify this by opening Chrome's dev tools while you run your code; you'll see that the `onPlayerStateChange` method is complaining that there is no `done` variable).

The solution would be to move the declaration of that variable outside of the `ready` method, like this:

```
var done = false;
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
});
```

Everything else can stay the same.